# Overpic+graphics full size image

Tags: graphics, blank-page, overpic

I'm using graphics+overpic to create the title page of a book and I had a struggle eliminating a blank page that the code generated at the beginning of the book.

So I insert the image with overpic, it has the exact same height (I made sure of that) and a bit less width as the document. I eliminated the margins to get a full page image. This is the code that generates that blank page:

```
\newgeometry{
left=0mm,
right=0mm,
top=0mm,
bottom=0mm}

\begin{raggedright}
\begin{overpic}[height=1\textheight]{Portada.png}
 %To write inside the image
 \put (43,80) {\fontsize{32}{38}$Tercera$}
 \put (43,72) {\fontsize{32}{30}$Cruzada$}
\end{overpic}
\end{raggedright}

\restoregeometry
```

Now, I tried and tried and the only thing that works and still get me a full page image is

begin{overpic}[height=0.999\textheight]{Portada.png}

So I said to myself "ok, a round error of 0.001, no problem, I'll fix the image and it will work without the 0.999" but it doesn't! If I don't write the "0.999\textheight" the code will create a blank page.

My document size is this:

```
\geometry{
 screen,
 paperwidth=14.78cm,
 paperheight=19.71cm, 
 left=8mm,
 right=8mm,
 top=9mm,
 bottom=9mm}
```

Tecnically there is no problem but I'm dying to know wihy this happens. Does anyone have any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.